# Creating HtmlHelper.Raw Tag Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to implement a `Tag Helper` class in asp.net core which returns raw output of it's content.

Here is my attempt:

```
public class RawTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public RawTagHelper(IHtmlHelper _)
    {
        HtmlHelper = _;
    }

    private IHtmlHelper HtmlHelper { get; }

    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        ((IViewContextAware)HtmlHelper).Contextualize(ViewContext);

        output.TagName = null;
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(HtmlHelper.Raw(await output.GetChildContentAsync()));
    }
}
```

The issue is that HtmlHelper.Raw returns an object `DefaultTagHelperContent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the issue was that i was passing `await output.GetChildContentAsync()` to the HtmlHelper.Raw which accepts a string so i had to change

```
output.Content.SetHtmlContent(HtmlHelper.Raw(await output.GetChildContentAsync()));
```

to

```
output.Content.SetHtmlContent(HtmlHelper.Raw((await output.GetChildContentAsync()).GetContent()));
```

Then i realized that `SetHtmlContent` will encode that again as html element so i ended up getting the content of the element and use `SetContent` instead of `SetHtmlContent`.

So an HtmlHelper.Raw Tag Helper should look like that

```
public class RawTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = null;
        output.Content.SetContent((await output.GetChildContentAsync()).GetContent());
    }
}
```

usage..

```
<raw>Some text <div>Other text</div></raw>
```

output..

```
Some text <div>Other text</div>
```